# Implementation examples for common architectural patterns/idioms?

Tags: implementation, design-patterns, idioms

I was wondering where it is possible to find implementation as illustrative examples for commonly used architectural patterns/idioms

For example

1. Logging
2. Exception Handling
3. Archiving/Caching
4. User/Role/Policy/Permissions
5. Business Rules/Constraints
6. Data Access Objects
7. Objects dirty/update

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://cs.mum.edu/courses/cs525/Refs/VOD-12-27-99.PDF 
It has wide variety of examples of different implementation patterns in the field of software engineering.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this to [C# Architectural Patterns](https://dotnetcodr.com/architecture-and-patterns/) everyone!